# Differences in number of approximateEntries in Kafka Streams store if it is retrieved via streams.store() or in a processor via context.getStateStore

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We are accessing a state store that is used/filled by an aggregate() call in our stream DSL and also accessed in two other areas of our Kafka streams app.

One is just used for scheduled monitoring of the entries, created and accessed by:

```
val value: StoreQueryParameters[ReadOnlyKeyValueStore[String, Aggregated]] =
  StoreQueryParameters.fromNameAndType(config.stream.stateStoreName, QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore())

val store = streams.store(value)

// then later in a scheduled TimerThread
logger.info(store.approximateNumEntries())
```

the other place in the Kafka streams app is in a Processor used in a transfrom() call of the DSL:

```
[...].transform(
    ourTransformerSupplier(config.stream.stateStoreName),
    Named.as("ourTransformer"),
    config.stream.stateStoreName
  )

// Transformer code
def init(context: ProcessorContext): Unit = {
  this.context = context
  this.stateStore = context.getStateStore(stateStoreName).asInstanceOf[TimestampedKeyValueStore[String, Aggregated]]
[...]
// inside the transformers scheduled (WALL_CLOCK_TIME) punctuate:
logger.info(stateStore.approximateNumEntries())
```

The numbers differ by a magnitude of 10x to 20 times, while being executed about just the same time on the same instance. Of course we use the same state store name config (i.e. it is really the same store) and the actions taken in the processor have also an effect on the numbers of the monitoring piece of code. The difference magnitude is the roughly the same on every instance in the cluster.

I wondered if this has something to do with how the state store is returned in the processor by the API (TimestampedKeyValueStore instead of ReadOnlyKeyValueStore) but after looking at the library code this just seems to be an API wrapper.